# Error en controlador de subir imagenes, error en consola: POST <link> 404 not found

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, mongodb, heroku

ayer pude subir mi proyecto MEAN stack a heroku, configurar todo y ya se muestra, tengo algunos problemas en la consola, ya que cuando intento crear un artículo, arroja estos errores:

Este se muestra cuando recién abro la home de mi pagina la cual les adjuntare, para ver mejor [Pagina proyecto](https://arthuro-gomez-web-app.herokuapp.com/)

[image: Consola error]

y cuando intento crear un articulo me dice este error

[image: Error al crear articulo]

y en la parte de red de la consola muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Verifico en la base de datos y me lo crea, pero con imagen null y mi código en localhost, cuando se crea un articulo y la imagen es null, muestra el articulo pero con una imagen predefinida, por lo que me lleva a pensar que tampoco esta funcionando el controlador de mostrar los artículos, adjuntare el codigo donde me indica que hay error:

Este es el metodo en ArticleNewComponent.ts

```
imageUpload(data){ 
this.article.image = data.body.image;
}
```

Esta es la ruta en el backend

```
app.post('/upload-image/:id?', md_upload , ArticleController.upload);
```

Este es el controlador

```
upload: (req,res) => {

var file_name = 'Imagen no subida';

if(!req.files){
return res.status(404).send({
    status: 'error',
    message: file_name
});
}

 var file_path = req.files.file0.path;
 var file_split = file_path.split('\\');

 var file_name = file_split[2];

var extension_split = file_name.split('\.');
var file_ext = extension_split[1];

if(file_ext != 'png' && file_ext != 'jpeg' && file_ext != 'jpg' && file_ext != 'gif'){

fs.unlink(file_path, (err)=> {
    return res.status(200).send({
        status: 'error',
        message: 'La extension no es valida'
     });
    });
    } else {
      var articleId = req.params.id;

      if(articleId){
      Article.findOneAndUpdate({_id: articleId }, {image: file_name}, {new:true}, (err, 
        articleUpdated)=> {

        if(err || !articleUpdated){
            return res.status(200).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: 'Error al guardar la imagen de articulo!!'
           });
        }


        return res.status(200).send({
            status: 'success',
            article: articleUpdated
       });
    });

}else{
    return res.status(200).send({
        status: 'success',
        image: file_name
   }); 
}
}
```

Esto localmente funciona perfecto, si quieren ver mas acerca del código, adjunto mi github o pueden pedírmelo por acá [Repositorio Github](https://github.com/Emocrat3/Curso-React-Vue-js-Angular)

Agradeceria cualquier ayuda :)